# Define custom color

Tags: php, jquery, css, colors

```
border:3px solid black;
```

In the above example, you can set color by saying the color's name. There is also a wide verity of color name out there also.

And so my question is this. Is there a way to define your own custom color name on your site in css, javascript/jquery, or even php.

Why? (I'm partially mad, but) In c# it can be handy to have a global variable to use that you can change and it would effect everything using it, and I would love a similar effect.

You may ask "Couldn't you just use class="myColor"?" I COULD, but I don't always use the color the same way, I sometimes use it for borders, background, or even text. Also, I'd have to give it a class, rather than declare it in css, which for a border can be weird.

Basically, I was wondering if there's anything even close to what I am looking for, be it css (so doubt it), jquery, or even php. Considering I want to use this color name in css I doubt this is possible, but I would love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set variables using a CSS PreProcessor such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Using SASS it looks like this.

```
$lightGrey :#5e5e5el;

a {
    color: $lightGrey;
}
```

Output:

```
a {
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
```

Comment: Wow, lots of answers. I've actually seen these mentioned before, never knew what they were. More reading than I wanted, but what they can do seems awesome =p I must have used fairly bad search key words to not find this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a color value as opposed to a named color:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)" or "[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)" to do that.

```css
@myColor: #FFCC00;
...
background-color: @myColor;
...
border: 1px solid @myColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) has this useful feature (and many others).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into CSS for this. You may want to look into [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). With it you could easily put a color in a variable and use it throughout your CSS. LESS is designed to make CSS more DRY.

Here is the description of it from that link:

> LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions. LESS runs on both the client-side (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) and server-side, with Node.js and Rhino.

Answer (score 0):

[This may be coming to CSS eventually](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/).

Comment: yay :) To bad none of these PreProcessors have the same syntax.